# Scrapy: 403 Error on all requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

My scrapy crawler uses [random proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) and it works on my computer. But when I run it on a vps, it return 403 error on every requests.

```
2018-05-26 09:43:18 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Proxy user pass not found
2018-05-26 09:43:18 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Using proxy <http://104.237.210.29:2716>, 20 proxies left
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.yelp.com/> (failed 1 times): 403 Forbidden
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Proxy user pass not found
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Using proxy <http://104.237.210.173:5195>, 20 proxies left
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.yelp.com/> (failed 1 times): 403 Forbidden
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Proxy user pass not found
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.proxies] DEBUG: Using proxy <http://104.237.210.93:3410>, 20 proxies left
2018-05-26 09:43:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.yelp.com/> (failed 1 times): 403 Forbidden
```

I manually checked the proxies on firefox on the vps and I can access the websites without any error.

This my settings, it's the same as the one on my computer:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   # 'monitor.middlewares.MonitorDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
   # Proxies
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    # Proxies end
    # Useragent
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'random_useragent.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    # Useragent end
}

# Random useragent list
USER_AGENT_LIST = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\useragents.txt"

# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 5
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

# Proxy list containing entries like
# http://host1:port
# http://username:password@host2:port
# http://host3:port
PROXY_LIST = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\proxies.txt"

# Proxy mode
# 0 = Every requests have different proxy
# 1 = Take only one proxy from the list and assign it to every requests
# 2 = Put a custom proxy to use in the settings
PROXY_MODE = 0
```

Comment: Where do you get the 403 error? From the proxy or from yelp? Is there an error message body with the 403 response? 403 is a typical response when you are trying to access a resource that requires authentication, but you are not logged in. Retrying is not a proper response to a 403, what you need to do is to authenticate and get a proper login token for the resource you are trying to access.

Comment: @HåkenLid The website doesn't require to login. When I access the website without proxy it shows a 403 Forbidden error. But when using a proxy, I can access the site as normal. Problem is on scrapy it's gettings 403 error even when on proxies. I think the scrapy-proxies is not working properly.

Comment: Maybe because the browser automatically redirects http to https? I don't know how we can figure out this problem for you with only the information you have provided. What exactly are the response and request http headers? There's always a reason why you would get a 403. Http status codes are not returned at random.

Comment: I'm using the scrapy framework. It automatically redirects from http to https and uses correct headers. Besides that, I've the exact copy of the script on my computer and it works fine on my pc.

Comment: You have to figure out where the 403 error comes from and why you get that response. There's probably some difference between your environments. Maybe there's some sort of firewall blocking proxy traffic? Who knows. The http responses might contain clues. You should include the full http responses (headers and body) with your question, not just the status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you get 403 because the robots.txt disallow robots on the whole website, or part of website you are scrapping.

Then first of all, write in the settings.py `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`. I don't see it in your settings here.

Do not consider the robots.txt is not enough generaly. You must make up your user agent as a conventional browser, in the settings.py too. For instance: `USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7'`
The best to do is create a list of bunch of user agent in the settings, for instance like this:

```
USER_AGENT_LIST = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7',
    ...,
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10'
]
```

you seem to did it. Then to make it random, and you seem to did too.

Finally, this is kinda optional but I let you see if it is useful for you, to write a `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3` in settings.py where the value is 1 at least. The ideal is to make it random too. It makes up your spider acting like a browser. As far as I know, a too quick download delay can make the website understand this is a robot made up with a fake user agent. If the webmaster has a lot of experience, he makes rules with many barriers to protect his website from robots.

I tested it this morning for the same problem like yours, in my scrapy shell. I hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is but found many people with problems using scrapy_proxies. I'm using [scrapy-rotating-proxies](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-rotating-proxies/) instead. It's maintained by [kmike](https://pypi.org/user/kmike/) who maintains the scrapy framework too, so I guess it's better.